# Navigating to different activities in a list Cardview

Tags: java, android

I have created a `recyclerview` with one `Cardview` that displays an array list and I want to set an **onclick** listener such that when I click on one `cardview` it navigates to different activities with different contents.

Comment: show your code?

Comment: just needed advise provide if possible

Comment: can you share screen or view for better understanding?